# Is unordered map behaving as expected in C++?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I am new to C++ and I don't get to understand the logic of the following code:

```
#include <unordered_map>

std::unordered_map<int, int> maxima;

void update(int key, int value) {
    auto it = maxima.find(key);
    if (it == maxima.end()) {
        maxima.emplace(key, value);
    } else if (value > it->second) {
        it->second = value;
    }
}
```

I have tested it with the following:

```
int main() {
  update(3,6);
  update(1,6);
  update(4,6);
  update(4,9);
  update(2,9);
  update(1,3);
  update(3,18);

  for (auto x : maxima)
    cout << x.first << " " << x.second << endl;
  
  return 0;
}
```

and it returns:

```
2 9
4 9
1 6
3 18
```

How come the (1,3) has disappeared from the output?

Comment: The map already have the `1,6` pair when you attempt to add `1,3`. And because the condition `if (value > it->second)` you never modify the value for the key `1`. It's not the behavior of the map, it's the behavior of the `update` function you need to look at.

Comment: *How come the (1,3) has disappeared from the output?* -- Nothing "disappeared".  The value was never in the map.  You should have focused on how you are populating and changing the map.

Comment: *Is unordered map behaving as expected in C++?* -- It is.  If it was not behaving as expected, thousands of programmers around the world would have reported the issue.

Comment: Could you explain why you expect (1,3) to be there, but not (3,6) and (4,6)?

Comment: Note that your solution performs double lookup in case of the key is not in the map. Possibly better might be something like: `auto p = maxima.emplace(key, value); if (!p.second) p.first.second = std::max(p.first.second, value);`.

Comment: *"I don't get to understand the logic of the following code:"* -- could you add an explanation of what you *do* understand, of why you expect `1 3` in the output? Not necessarily a line-by-line explanation; a more abstract, higher-level explanation would also be good. That is, what is calling `update(1,3);` supposed to accomplish? The explanation could be at the level of *"make sure that `maxima[1]` is `3` when `update()` returns"* (but presumably the explanation would not be exactly that since that is not what `update()` does).

Answer (score 4):

The `update` function can be read as *if the key is not present then add the key/value pair to the map, otherwise if the new value is greater than the existing value then replace the existing value with the new value, otherwise do nothing*.

I'm sure you can see that under this rule the `(1,3)` pair never gets added because of the existing `(1,6)` pair.

The overall logic is to store in the unordered map the maximum value associated with any given key. For the key of 1 that value is 6.